# Joining Key and Values in Dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am a beginner in Python. Struggling in joining the Key and Values.

```
d = {'vlan 158': ['  name MARKE', '  mode vpc']}
```

Desired output :

```
vlan 158
  name MARKE
  mode vpc
```

I tried many things like:

```
print('\n'.join(['\n'.join(item) for item in d]))
print '\n'.join(d)
```

All these are not giving me the expected output. Any Idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you this simple solution:

```
d = {'vlan 158': ['  name MARKE', '  mode vpc']}

for k in d:
    print(k + '\n' + '\n'.join(d[k]))
```

The output is:

```
vlan 158
  name MARKE
  mode vpc
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d = {'vlan 158': ['  name MARKE', '  mode vpc']}
for key in d:
    print(key)
    print(*d.get(key), sep='\n')
```

You can use this to get required output. But note that operator '*' only works on python3.

Basically, if I have an array,

```
a=[34,45,56]
```

I can access the individual elements by

```
print(*a)
```

This give an output of

```
34 45 56
```

Comment: Or just `print(key, *d[key], sep='\n')`.